# Angular 2 Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute - Components inside components

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I have to create a form , And I want to be more clear about components

The main idea of form is:

FormComponent
|**>
    FieldComponent
      |**> InputComponent of Form

So I Have  PartnerFormComponent:

Html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="partnerForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <!--<legal-information
      [(partner)]="partner" [(partnerConfiguration)]="partnerConfiguration" ></legal-information>-->
    <combo-billing-entity [(formGroup)]="partnerForm"       [(partner)]="partner" [(partnerConfiguration)]="partnerConfiguration"></combo-billing-entity>

    <div class="buttons_form">
      <button class="save_button_form" type="submit" [disabled]="!partnerForm.valid">
        Add
      </button>

      <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green"
         routerLink="/partners">
        <i class="material-icons">Cancel</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'partner-form',
  templateUrl: './partner-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./partner-form.component.css'],
  entryComponents:[LegalInformationComponent]
})
export class PartnerFormComponent implements OnInit {


  private partnerForm: FormGroup;
  title: string;
  partner: Partner = new Partner();
  partnerConfiguration: PartnerConfiguration = new PartnerConfiguration();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private partnerService: PartnerService
  ) {  }



  ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id = params['id'];

      if (!id)
        return;

      .....

    });
  }
```

then from component i have html Combo:

```
  <div class="components_situation">
    <div class="field_form_title">
      {{title}} <span class="is_required_form" [hidden]="!isRequired">*</span>
    </div>
    <div [formGroup]="formGroup" >
    <select id="billingEntity" [(ngModel)]="partnerConfiguration.fakeBillingEntity"
            formControlName="billingEntity"
            [class.invalid]="form.controls['billingEntity'].touched && !form.controls['billingEntity'].valid"
    >
      <option disabled hidden [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue">-- select --</option>
      <option *ngFor="let obj of billingEntities" [value]="obj.value" >{{obj.name}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="some_explanation_form_field">{{someExplanation}}</div>
  </div>
```

And TS:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonFieldFormComponent} from "../../common-field-form-component";
import {BillingService} from "../../../../../../services/billing/billing.service";
import {BillingEntitity} from "../../../../../../model/billing_entity";
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'combo-billing-entity',
  templateUrl: './combo-billing-entity.component.html'
})
export class ComboBillingEntityComponent extends CommonFieldFormComponent implements OnInit {
  private selectUndefinedOptionValue:any;
  billingEntities:BillingEntitity[] = [];

  @Input()
  private formGroup:FormGroup;


  constructor(private billingService: BillingService, private formBuilder:FormBuilder)
 {
   super();
   this.isRequired=true;
   this.title="Billing Entity";
   this.someExplanation="Identifies entity responsible for billing invoice";
   this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      billingEntity :['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

But after all I have this error:

ComboBillingEntityComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
    at _throwError (forms.es5.js:1852)
    at setUpControl (forms.es5.js:1760)
    at FormGroupDirective.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.es5.js:4733)
    at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.es5.js:5321)
    at FormControlName.webpackJsonp.../../../forms/@angular/forms.es5.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.es5.js:5239)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10831)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12330)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12269)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13130)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13071)

Any Idea how to bind inputs to main form.. what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hey, how did it go with the answers? Was either suitable for you, or would you want further assistance? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few issues in your form. You are trying to use two-way-binding in your Input fields, for example `[(formGroup)]="partnerForm"` But then you are nowhere using `@Output` to actually trigger the two-way-binding, so you are not using it properly.

The form object is indeed an object, and objects are mutable in JS and passed by reference. Sometimes this is not desirable behavior, but in this scenario we want that, where we have nested components. So whatever you do to form fields in child component, parent will be aware, so you don't actually need the two-way-binding.

Secondly, please avoid using `[(ngModel)]` in reactive forms. I've noticed that weird behavior can occur, which is understandable, since we then have two bindings, to the ngModel variable and the other is the form control variable. Utilize the form controls instead, and remove all ngModel from your templates. You can set values to the form control, that will basically function as two-way-binding as you can access the form control value from TS as well any time you like. So `[(ngModel)]`

Build your whole form in parent and then pass the formgroup over to the child, or alernatively pass a nested formgroup to your child. So here in your parent you actually want to build the form:

```
this.partnerForm = this.fb.group({
  billingEntity: ['hey I am initial value']
})
```

Above you cans set initial value to `billingEntity`, or if you need at some other point manually set a default value you can do that by: `this.partnerForm.get('billingEntity').setValue(...)`

We now pass this form to the child:

```
<combo-billing-entity [partnerForm]="partnerForm"></combo-billing-entity>
```

and in child we register it as an `Input`:

```
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
```

Then we can then just use it, e.g:

```
<div [formGroup]="partnerForm">
  <input formControlName="billingEntity" />
</div>
```

I see that you are trying to use `[(ngModel)]` there, but as mentioned, you can drop that and use the form control instead. The value is stored nicely in `formGroup.get('billingEntity').value` and as earlier mentioned, if you need to set the value at some point you can do that. But all your form values are nicely stored in the form object, i.e `partnerForm.value`.

Here's a simple demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/AuidEMaaURsBPfDP8k0Q?p=preview

I suggest you read about nested forms, this one is pretty good to get started with: [Nested Model-driven Forms](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Your component will have to implement [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) and register it is a multi dependency. Pascal Precht has a very good blog post on [custom form controls in Angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).

In short words, after you implement `ControlValueAccessor` by defining functions `writeValue`, `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched`, you'll have to provide the existing value so Angular can know that you're trying to use it a form control.

```
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ComboBillingEntityComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
  // ...
})
class ComboBillingEntityComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  // ...
}
```

After this, you can use `formControlName` on `<combo-billing-entity>` tag in your templates:

```
<combo-billing-entity formControlName="billingInfo"></combo-billing-entity>
```